# How does compilers differentiate same variable created from different instantiations

Tags: java, php, python

I am very premature to programming.I don't even know whether the question itself is right.I will explain what i meant here plainly.

- User 1 Login to the website.So all the objects and others are run with respect to the program code written.
- Now user 2 login to the website at same time say,so again these codes are run parallel to the user 1 script.So these codes must contain almost same varibales as user 1 in the codes.right ?

How does PHP,Python,Java differentiate these same variables run in the memory at same time ?
You can't have same variables with different values at same time in memory right ?

Comment: Typically, there are separate instances of these objects at run-time.  In the context of a web application, you can tie an instance of something to the session itself.

Answer (score 1):

Nope ... the runtimes usually store these variables in completely separate variable tables, namespaces, add custom identifiers to the variable names, etc. if it was handling multiple users in a single runtime environment. In the case of a webserver, each person that visits a site (i.e., connection) is a typically a completely separate instance of the runtime with it's own memory footprint... it would be like running multiple copies of the same program.  If you have two Word docs open, typing in one doesn't change the other one, does it?  The same principal is true here as well ...

Comment: Thanks for answering.I kind of heard about custom identifiers for every variable names on instantiation itself from google.Variable tables is kind of new info anyway i will learn about it from google now.Is this the same way for all langauges ?

Comment: The (too-broad) question was about Java, PHP and Python. You should qualify your answer (about the separate runtime instances) because it doesn't make any sense for Java. Also not clear what you mean with "add custom identifiers to the variable names". For every concurrent user? Could you give a concrete example of that?

Comment: The question was very broad, so I was giving a very broad response ... for instance, while he didn't specifically ask this, in C++, the variables at the compiler level have additional identifiers added so that classes, namespaces, etc. work when variable names are duplicated in each.  The same would be true of a JIT compiler for other common languages that compile to bytecode or an executable at runtime, or transpilers like HipHop that compile PHP to C++, etc.